# Regex validation - Domain email address

Tags: javascript, regex

i can't find a regex to check the correct format of my domain, only the domain, not the whole email!!

It must accept format like :  @xxxx.xx or xxxx.xx

Now my reg is like that:

```
 var re = /^((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;
```

But it doesnt accept the '@' ahaed. Can u help me??

Comment: Just a side note: keep in mind that the client can in many way manipulate the form, so you should check aswell on the server side if the e-mail is actually in the desired format, assuming there is a server side afterward.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use a regex for this. Instead a validation routine in a library or I would try to resolve the IP or domain name to check if it is OK. The problem here is that you don't cover valid cases for domain names. You have to cover every case possible with RFC and this is not a job for regexes I think. Please have a look at [Mail::RFC822::Address: regexp-based address validation](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) to know what I mean. The regex could be a first line of defense but my worry is about valid but rejected cases

Comment: I know and i will check the fomat also in the server side, but i like the runtime validation of javascript and i want it in my field. So that if the domain is not well formed the user can't do anithing

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function

```
  function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }
```

Comment: This not work... it only accept the email format ex: aaaa@aaaa.aa . I need something that accept ex : aaaa.aa and @aaaa.aa

Answer (score 0):

[The email regex used in HTML5's email input fields](https://developers.whatwg.org/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#e-mail-state-(type=email)) is the following:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

And this is it modified to just the domain with or without the @:

```
/^@?[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Tightened up to require at least two letters in the last part (which disqualifies IP addresses):

```
/^@?[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,62})$/
```

Comment: Unfortunatly in this way it accepts also format like 'aaaa' and 'aaa.a' that are no valid in an email address.

Comment: Yes, this is true. See the rationale in the HTML5 spec. [Here's a regex that is strictly valid](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) and I don't think you'd want to use that because strictly valid also means using things no one really uses in real life either. Additionally, new top level domains can now be registered. Someone could register `.foobar` tomorrow. Or someone could use a domain that just doesn't exist. I am editing to tighten it up slightly, but it can't be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution! Simply adding "^@?" at the beginning of the reg string.

```
 var re = /^@?((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;
```

In this way the field will be valid only if the user insert a domain with or without the @.